# Is Maltego the best forensic/intelligence solution out there?

Tags: web-application, appsec, forensics

I am looking for the best intelligence forensic software that will give me the best solution for gathering information around the web.

please recommend me the best software out there ... and if you think you are qualified enough to gather information about import export I can pay top dollar for your time.

Comment: Check out this recent title -- https://www.amazon.com/Down-Rabbit-Hole-OSINT-Journey/dp/0995687544/ -- where the author covers FOCA, Maltego, Nmap, Spiderfoot, Shodan, Censys, LeakDBs, Dorking, Robtex, Netcraft, and general OSINT-based Targeting from Kali Linux. There is no one-size fits all solution for forensics or intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best forensic intelligence tool every made is GREP.  Oah don't, forget PCRE,  I can tell you from more than a decade of experience that a regular expression tool will be able to detect any pattern and any violation you could possibly need.

Google is good at "gathering information around the web".

Comment: what is the most easy /friendly way of using those softwares ?

Comment: @david umm...  getting a computer science degree from an accredited university?

Answer (score 0):

Maltego is very cool, but it’s also just one tool.  You may try searching for OSINT (Open Source Intelligence) and review the documented techniques and tools that could help you discover the information you are after.

There are also groups/companies that develop commercial plugins designed to boost intelligence gathering capabilities – like [SocialNet](http://packetninjas.net/tools/socialnet.html).  Sometimes these tools can be challenging to use because they violate the Terms of Service of the target systems.

Outside of using specialty tools searching via the popular search engines is bound to help.  A caveat is to learn search engine limitations that impede OSINT work.  [Paterva](http://paterva.com/) & [FOCA Pro](http://www.informatica64.com/foca.aspx) training courses talk about search engine limitations – here is an example:

[Exalead](http://www.exalead.com/search/) reports **20,227,717** search results for "john smith":

[image]

But when trying to retrieve results after **2,000**, you'll get:

[image]

Comment: Similar to Maltego would be Palantir, and Palantir can scour the web using KapowSoftware, as well as point-solution addons such as SiloBreaker and RecordedFuture (which also have integrations with Maltego. another Maltego integration point comes from RiskIQ)